# PeerJS connects in Chrome but not other browsers

Tags: javascript, webrtc, peerjs

We are starting to explore peer-to-peer networking through the browser in PeerJS. I am new to WebRTC. I'm currently trying to get two browser tabs **on the same computer** to talk to each other **over the local network**. The code we're currently testing is taken almost directly from the example code on their [Github page](https://github.com/peers/peerjs):

First we run PeerServer locally using Node:

```
const { PeerServer } = require('peer');
const server = PeerServer({port: 9000, path: '/pjs'});
```

Then we try to connect:

```
import Peer from 'peerjs';
var CreatePeer = function(id) {
    this.peer = new Peer(id, {host: 'localhost', port: 9000, path: '/pjs', debug: 3}); 
}

var Connect = function(otherUserID) {
    this.peer.connect(otherUserID);
}

//...
CreatePeer("myID");
//...
Connect("theirID");
```

The above works fine in Chrome and we can even exchange messages using additional code I've omitted here. However, in Firefox, the `this.peer.connect(otherUserID)` line fails and displays this error in the browser console:

> ICE failed, your TURN server appears to be broken, see about:webrtc for more details

The `about:webrtc` page has a log with these two lines repeated over and over:

> LOGGING SUSPENDED: a connection is active in a Private Window 
>   LOGGING RESUMED: no connections are active in a Private Window

In Edge, the `peer.connect` line instead throws this exception in the console:

> TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'createDataChannel'

When I research this error I get results from 2016 - 2017 before Edge supported WebRTC. As far as I can tell, Edge should support WebRTC since late 2017, but maybe I've misunderstood something.

**Why would the above code work Chrome but not in Edge or Firefox?**

Comment: Please show the code you've omitted. The [Firefox error](https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/rev/8ed108064bf1c83e508208e069a90cffb4045977/dom/media/PeerConnection.jsm#1905) you show happens asynchronously later, not from that line. Aren't you supposed to use `conn.on('open', () => {})`?

Comment: Hi @Kevin. Were you able to fix the peerjs for firefox? I am getting the same issue.

Comment: @AbdullahKhan I don't recall finding a solution to this issue. That portion of the project is on the backburner, so I haven't looked at it in a while.

Answer (score 2):

Edge is [not supported in peer.js](https://github.com/peers/peerjs#browsers-support) although there is an issue raised to revisit that in the context of [Chromium-based Edge](https://github.com/peers/peerjs/issues/615).

Comment: Thanks, although this doesn't address the part of the question about Firefox.